# How to implement simple dependencies between DrRacket plugins?

Tags: plugins, ide, scheme, racket

I want to implement 2 DrRacket plugins or tools, where I have a dependency between one tool and the other. Essentially, one tool must have access to a function provided by the other tool. The current code I have is something like:

providing tool:

```
(provide tool@ extra-signature^)
(define-signature extra-signature^ (some-procedure))
(define tool@ 
(unit
  (import drracket:tool^)
  (export drracket:tool-exports^ extra-signature^)
  (define (phase1) void)
  (define (phase2) void)
  (define (some-procedure) void)
  ))
```

dependent tool:

```
(require extra-signature)
(provide tool@)
(define tool@
  (unit
  (import drracket:tool^ extra-signature^)
  (export drracket:tool-exports^)
  (define (phase1) void)
  (define (phase2) void)
  (some-procedure)
  ))
```

Trying to run DrRacket with above tools gives the error:

Error invoking tool #<path:/Users/...;("dependentTool.rkt")

define-unit-binding: unit argument expects an untagged import with signature extra-signature^, which this usage context does not supply

How can I actually implement such a dependency between DrRacket plugins?

Answer (score 0):

defining some-procedure at the top level of the providing module, alongside tool@, then using require with only-in in the dependent module